# UTF 8 encoded Japanese string in XML

Tags: c++, xml, unicode, character

I am trying to create a SOAP call with Japanese string. The problem I faced is that when I encode this string to UTF8 encoded string, it has many control characters in it (e.g. 0x1B (Esc)). If I remove all such control characters to make it a valid SOAP call then the Japanese content appears as garbage on server side.
How can I create a valid SOAP request for Japanese characters? Any suggestion is highly appreciated. 
I am using C++ with MS-DOM.

With Best Regards.

Comment: What makes you say that a SOAP request with UTF-8 encoding is not valid? Does the server not accept XML with `encoding="utf-8"`?

Comment: Those "control" characters is part of the encoding of the Japanese characters, and should definitely not be removed. What happens when you don't remove them? Does the SOAP call work anyway?

Comment: The utf-8 characters should definitely stay inside the message. Maybe the problem is not the message itself but the creation of the message. Did you output your data as binary so no other conversion takes place?

Comment: I dump the complete request before sending it to server. I have taken out the data part from request. It is well formatted html data which is as follows:
<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-2022-jp">
</head>
<body>
<font face="Calibri, sans-serif" size="2">
<div>When: Occurs every <font face="$B#M#S(B $BL@D+(B, serif">&#0x1B$B7nMKF|(B</font> effective 2011/04/04 from 9:30 to 10:30 (GMT&amp;#43;09:00) Osaka, Sapporo, Tokyo.</div>
</body>
</html>

Comment: sounds like a transcoding problem, if a printable character encoded in your local encoding ([SHIFT_JIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shift_JIS) for example) is converted to [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) encoding, it shouldn't be a control character.

Comment: Server throws following error:
Request caused soap fault service.PARSE_ERROR parse error: Error on line 41 of document  : An invalid XML character (Unicode: 0x1b) was found in the element content of the document. Nested exception: An invalid XML character (Unicode: 0x1b) was found in the element content of the document.

Comment: Did you try to escape the 0x1b instead of removing? Maybe your server expect that the valid UTF8 character has the be escaped.

Comment: `&#1B;` is not legal in XML 1.0. It's allowed in XML 1.1 but it's still extremely inadvisable. The ESC character shouldn't be included in an XML document; suggest fixing the HTML from its broken format before encoding into XML.

Answer (score 3):

If I remember correctly it's true, the first 32 unicode code points are not allowed as characters in XML documents, even escaped with `&#`. Not sure whether they're allowed in HTML or not, but certainly the server thinks they're not allowed in your requests, and it gets the only meaningful vote.

I notice that your document claims to be encoded in `iso-2022-jp`, not `utf-8`. And indeed, the sequence of characters `ESC $ B` that appears in your document is valid iso-2022-jp. It indicates that the data is switching encodings (from ASCII to a 2-byte Japanese encoding called JIS X 0208-1983).

But somewhere in the process of constructing your request, something has seen that `0x1B` byte and interpreted it as a character U+001B, not realising that it's intended as one byte in data that's already encoded in the document encoding. So, it has XML-escaped it as a "best effort", even though that's not valid XML.

Probably, whatever is serializing your XML document doesn't know that the encoding is supposed to be `iso-2022-jp`. I imagine it thinks it's supposed to be serializing the document as ASCII, ISO-Latin-1, or UTF-8, and the `<meta>` element means nothing to it (that's an HTML way of specifying the encoding anyway, it has no particular significance in XML). But I don't know MS-DOM, so I don't know how to correct that.

If you just remove the `ESC` characters from iso-2022-jp data, then you conceal the fact that the data has switched encodings, and so the decoder will continue to interpret all that `7nMK` stuff as ASCII, when it's supposed to be interpreted as JIS X 0208-1983. Hence, garbage.

Something else strange -- the `iso-2022-jp` code to switch back to ASCII is `ESC ( B`, but I see `|(B</font>` in your data, when I'd expect the same thing to happen to the second ESC character as happened to the first: `&#0x1B(B</font>`. Similarly, `$B#M#S(B` and `$BL@D+(B` are mangled attempts to switch from ASCII to JIS X 0208-1983 and back, and again the `ESC` characters have just disappeared rather than being escaped.

I have no explanation for why some `ESC` characters have disappeared and one has been escaped, but it cannot be coincidence that what you generate looks almost, but not quite, like valid `iso-2022-jp`. I think iso-2022-jp is a 7 bit encoding, so part of the problem might be that you've taken iso-2022-jp data, and run it through a function that converts ISO-Latin-1 (or some other 8 bit encoding for which the lower half matches ASCII, for example any Windows code page) to UTF-8. If so, then this function leaves 7 bit data unchanged, it won't convert it to UTF-8. Then when interpreted as UTF-8, the data has ESC characters in it.

If you want to send the data as UTF-8, then first of all you need to actually convert it out of iso-2022-jp (to wide characters or to UTF-8, whichever your SOAP or XML library expects). Secondly you need to label it as UTF-8, not as iso-2022-jp. Finally you need to serialize the whole document as UTF-8, although as I've said you might already be doing that.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by Steve Jessop, it looks like you have encoded the text as iso-2022-jp, not UTF-8.  So the first thing to do is to check that and ensure that you have proper UTF-8.

If the problem still persists, consider encoding the text.

The simplest option is "hex encoding" where you just write the hex value of each byte as ASCII digits.  e.g. the 0x1B byte becomes "1B", i.e. 0x31, 0x42.

If you want to be fancy you could use MIME or even UUENCODE.